# C# The best way to convert html not well-formed to PDF

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext

I want to build a method to convert HTML content to PDF file. HTML is email content. It's very long and complex. HTML of email is not well-formed. 
I have used itextSharp library. But the results from this library are not well. Beside, The itextSharp 's performance is slow. 
Is there the best way to make it?

Comment: Two possible solutions: 1. use NSoup to clean up the HTML before you pass it on to iTextSharp 2. Wait a couple of weeks until a html2pdf add-on for iText 7 is released, which will be a lot more robust with regards to invalid html.

Comment: As for as performance goes: 1. Show your code 2. Show your html 3. Show your metrics

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
I've used the method on http://vh4u.blogspot.com/2016/01/convert-html-to-pdf-using-c.html  to convert HTML to PDF file.
You can test with an advertisement email.
I cannot convert or lack email content if an email contains complex CSS format.

Comment: Please show your HTML and the code you used to clock the performance.

Comment: Link source code to convert HTML to PDF: http://www.mediafire.com/file/2a1xaa1ck6k0yb1/ConvertHTML2PDF.rar
Link HTML templates: http://www.mediafire.com/file/1h6ugtts96d2twp/SendGridFreeEmailTemplates.zip
Please download and check them. Thanks!!!

Comment: I am not going to download a RAR file from a spyware infected website. Either put the code in your question directly, or put it on a *reputable* website, for example as a gist on GitHub, or on PasteBin.

Comment: My code: http://pastebin.com/2rnfuKhk

Comment: OK, and now you edit your question to put that link in it, and you hope & pray that a Stack Overflow moderator finds that enough to reopen your question. Maybe it's better if you start a new question, where you only talk about the performance, and give all of the information the first time around. Because 19 hours to extract useful information from you, that's just too long.

Comment: Our C# PDF Library http://IronPDF.com deals with malformed html well as it uses a Chromium renderer similar to Google Chrome.

A simple code sample:  `using IronPdf;
IronPdf.HtmlToPdf Renderer = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
// Render an HTML document or snippet as a string
Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf("<h1>Hello World</h1>").SaveAs("html-string.pdf");`  More advice available with our [C# html to pdf tutorial](https://ironpdf.com/tutorials/html-to-pdf/)

Answer (score 1):

iTextSharp's `XMLWorker` expects valid, well-formed HTML as input. If you know that your HTML will not be valid, then you need to use a HTML cleanup tool. One of such tools is NSoup, which is a . NET port of JSoup. Another is HTML Agility Pack.

EDIT: iText 7's pdfHTML is better equipped at dealing with malformed HTML.